# laravel project not loading css with apache artisan serve working fine

Tags: php, laravel, apache, virtualhost

I've created a Laravel Project, which I have deployed previously with apache2, and working great.

As I finished with my latest deployment, I found that no external CSS was being loaded when I was done with. So I did a check on all step many times over, but I don't think I have missed on anything.

However, upon running with `php artisan serve` everything works fine.

Here is my virtual_host config file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@project
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/project/public/index.php
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    <Directory /var/www/html/project/public>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Did you try hard reload with ctrl+shift+R ?

Comment: yes..tried everything with reload, emptied cache also. Nothing worked.

Comment: You have set your `DocumentRoot` to the index.php file. You should set it to the folder instead. So it should be `DocumentRoot /var/www/html/project/public`

Comment: Ok. I'll check it @MrPixelDream

Comment: in console check what error you are getting while loading css and js files

Comment: 404 (Not Found). Basically, its not able to locate the css/js/img folders in public.

Comment: show console screen shot instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In virtualhost configuration, you should try using

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@project
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/project/public
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    <Directory /var/www/html/project/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Remove `public` folder from `<Directory>` and also remove `index.php` from `DocumentRoot`.

Comment: DocumentRoot I understand, but why do I need to remove public from directory? This worked tho :|